# Why am I getting "C4800: 'int': forcing value to bool" with ALL bool values?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, c++-cli, compiler-warnings

I am getting this C4800 warning and it points to a line of code that has NO int values associated with it:

```
CO.Value = (GE_DUAL.Value & GE_SINGLE.Value) | (!GE_DUAL.Value & !IN_TMR.Value);
```

Every `.Value` property is of type `bool`.

I'm using VS2015, C++/CLI, and have found no references in my code to the win32 type `BOOL`, though I have derived my own type BOOL from which each of these properties is cast.

I have over 200 other `.cpp` files in this project with thousands of lines of similar code and yet I only get this warning for this exact line.

**This more of a curiosity than a concern, I can easily get rid of the error by using logical operators** *(see below)* **, but if anyone has any ideas I like to hear them.** *I did search this error before posting, but never got a satisfactory answer (mostly people WERE using `int` types and having issues casting.)*

```
CO.Value = (GE_DUAL.Value && GE_SINGLE.Value) || (!GE_DUAL.Value && !IN_TMR.Value);
```

Three line down I have this line:

```
DUAL.Value = GE_DUAL.Value & !IN_TMR.Value;
```

Which gets no warnings...
Here's a more complete list of involved code:

```
public ref class BOOL : IPS::Properties::Bool
{
public:
  BOOL() : Bool() {}
  BOOL(bool val) : Bool() { Value = val;}
  operator bool() { return (bool)ValueAsObject;}
  BOOL(BOOL% b) { m_Value = b.m_Value;}
};
```

...

```
  BOOL^             m_IN_TMR;
  BOOL^             m_GE_DUAL;
  BOOL^             m_GE_SINGLE;
  BOOL^             m_CO;
```

...

```
  virtual property BOOL%  IN_TMR
  {
    BOOL% get();
    void set(BOOL% val);
  }
  virtual property BOOL%  GE_DUAL
  {
    BOOL% get();
    void set(BOOL% val);
  }
  virtual property BOOL%  GE_SINGLE
  {
    BOOL% get();
    void set(BOOL% val);
  }      
  virtual property BOOL%  CO
  {
    BOOL% get();
    void set(BOOL% val);
  }
```

...

```
void _TR_VOTE_MODE::IN_TMR::set(BOOL% val)
{
  m_IN_TMR = %val;
}  
BOOL% _TR_VOTE_MODE::GE_DUAL::get()
{
  return *m_GE_DUAL;
}
void _TR_VOTE_MODE::GE_DUAL::set(BOOL% val)
{
  m_GE_DUAL = %val;
}  
BOOL% _TR_VOTE_MODE::GE_SINGLE::get()
{
  return *m_GE_SINGLE;
}
void _TR_VOTE_MODE::GE_SINGLE::set(BOOL% val)
{
  m_GE_SINGLE = %val;
}  
BOOL% _TR_VOTE_MODE::CO::get()
{
  return *m_CO;
}
```

...

```
CO.Value = CI.Value;
if ( CI.Value )
{
  CO.Value = (GE_DUAL.Value & GE_SINGLE.Value) | (!GE_DUAL.Value & !IN_TMR.Value); // Warning C4800??
  if ( CO.Value )
  {
    TMR.Value = IN_TMR.Value;
    DUAL.Value = GE_DUAL.Value & !IN_TMR.Value;
    SINGL.Value = GE_SINGLE.Value & !GE_DUAL.Value;
    ZERO.Value = ! GE_SINGLE.Value;
  }
  else
  {
    U.Value = ReportBadParam(0);
    TMR.Value = false;
    DUAL.Value = false;
    SINGL.Value = false;
    ZERO.Value = false;
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**
I did some testing and found, as unlikely as it seemed, that this line of code was unique even among my many other 10's of thousands of lines of code. It was simply an issue of using the arithmetic operators ONLY. All other lines that I thought were similar had some sort of logical operator in them (intermixed with arithmetic)

It appears to be this part of the line:

```
(GE_DUAL.Value & GE_SINGLE.Value) ===> int
```

because that is arithmetic, and the other part is logical:

```
(!GE_DUAL.Value & !IN_TMR.Value) ===> bool
```

therefor the whole line is implicitly cast to int:

```
(GE_DUAL.Value & GE_SINGLE.Value) | (!GE_DUAL.Value & !IN_TMR.Value)

{bool} != {{int} | {bool}};
 {int} == {{int} | {bool}};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am getting this C4800 warning and it points to a line of code that has NO int values associated with it

Bitwise operations are [arithmetic operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic) and boolean operands are implicitly converted to `int` due to [integral promotion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#integral_promotion). Result of arithmetic operator of operands of type `int` is also `int`.

as for why MS compiler generates such warnings in one case and does not in others I can only guess that it can only predict value in some situations.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have a question about your rewrite: What happened to `IN_TMR.Value`?

Comment: Ah sorry end of friday, did not look deeply and thought that in both cases used the same values. Removed